# Can I get a horizontal scrollbar at the top and the bottom of a grid, when using Ext JS?

Tags: extjs, grid

Is there any way to get a horizontal scrollbar both at the top and at the bottom of a grid?

Here's what I'm talking about:
[image: grid]

Answer (score 0):

create an extra container (maybe as docked top) and override http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.panel.Table-method-syncHorizontalScroll func on your grid panel.